# Using an object like a lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a library with my own lock_guard, mutex etc. (basically mutex is a wrapper for nativ mutexes. Now I want to update several objects with several threads which have a lock inside of them.

Let's consider the class does look like that:

```
class ICanBeUpdated
{
public:
    friend mango::lock_guard<ICanBeUpdated>;

    ICanBeUpdated()
    {
        //set some values, etc
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //do something, takes some time
    }

private:
    void lock() //required by the guard
    {
        m_Lock.lock();
    }

    void unlock() //required by the guard
    {
        m_Lock.unlock();
    }

    mango::mutex m_Lock; //regular mutex
};
```

And I want to do something like that:

```
int main()
{
    mango::archive::thread_pool pool(mango::getCPUCores(), true); //just a thread_pool

    lambda((ICanBeUpdated* actor)  //sorry my IDE has no c++11 support so I tricked my own lambda
    {
        mango::lock_guard<ICanBeUpdated> guard(*actor); //Locks the object like it were a mutex to block other stakeholders from changing it while it's updating
        actor->Update(); 
        return 0; 
    }, 1); //exp1

    mango::shared_ptr<mango::vector<ICanBeUpdated*> > Actors = getActors(); //creates a vector of actors

    for (int i = 0; Actors->size() > i; ++i)
    {
        pool.run(exp1, Actors->at(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is it allowed to use a non-lock object with a lock inside like this?

```
mango::lock_guard<ICanBeUpdated> guard(*actor);
```

If no, why and do I always have to pass the mutex to the guard to lock it or should I implement another way to lock the actor?

Comment: What do you call *"non-lock object"* ? As `ICanBeUpdated` has `lock`/`unlock`...

Comment: A lock object is a class like `mutex` or a queued_mutex for me since in my opinion a mutex shouldn't have other responsibilities than locking/unlocking. `ICanBeUpdated` has a different purpose so it is no lock-object for me

Comment: Is it allowed? It's your library, you can do what you want. Are you asking whether you _should_ design your library this way? I'd just have a method returning `unique_lock<mango::mutex>` rather than a friend TBH. And that's assuming there's some benefit to writing your own mutex wrapper and not just using `std::mutex`.

Comment: `void Update() { mango::lock_guard<ICanBeUpdated> guard(m_Lock); /* do stuff */  }` seems more natural, but your way should work too.

Comment: kk, thank you, well I do not use std::mutex since my IDE has no C++11 support so I wrapped it around critical_section (under linux pthread_mutex) since in my opinion pthread_mutex and critical_section are ugly